# How to update Chromium source with local changes

Tags: svn, chromium

Recently I tried to build Chromium on my Windows 7 64bit machine, I check out the source of version 31.0.1650.4x, made some changes on the sources and build successfully. Then I updated the code to 31.0.1650.63 by running `gclient sync` gclient didn't complain the local changes  and made the update without any problem.

Yesterday I want to update the source to 32.0.1700.76, I run `gclinet sync` it complained the local changes and could not make the update. So I run `svn revert -R .` to revert the local changes and run `gclinet sync` again, it removed the whole `src` directory and checked out all again! Including the whole build dir, so my last build was lost.

My question is: How can I update the source without deleting and re-checking out just like my first update? I can accept revert the local changes but the check out is very sloooow, so I'd like to do the update based on the existing source, not check out all from the beginning.

Here is what I did to update the souce:

```
gclient config https://src.chromium.org/chrome/releases/32.0.1700.76
gclient sync
```

Is there something wrong? How can I do it right? Thanks.

Comment: I come to the similar situation. Downloading the 3-4 G files is painful. I hope it could update based on the existing files with some local changes (it can remove those local changes)